# Final digit of $a[n]a$, where $[n]$ is the $n$-th hyperoperator and $a \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, recurrence-relations, hyperoperation

While I was submitting a few sequences to the OEIS, I noticed an asymmetrical pattern involving the rightmost digits of an interesting set of well-known integer sequences.

Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, and assume that $[n]$ indicates the $n$-th hyperoperator (i.e., $[n]=[0] \Rightarrow$ *zeration*, $[n]=[1] \Rightarrow$ *addition*, $[n]=[2] \Rightarrow$ *multiplication*, $[n]=[3] \Rightarrow$ *exponentiation*, $[n]=[4] \Rightarrow$ *tetration*, $[n]=[5] \Rightarrow$ *pentation*, and so forth).

Now, since we are also assuming radix-$10$ (the usual decimal numeral system), it follows that
$a[0]a \pmod {10} = 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, \dots$ has a period length $10$.
$a[1]a \pmod {10} = 2, 4, 6, 8, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0, 2, 4, 6,\dots$ has a period length $5$.
$a[2]a \pmod {10} = 1, 4, 9, 6, 5, 6, 9, 4, 1, 0, 1, 4, 9, 6, 5, 6,\dots$ has a period length $10$.
$a[3]a \pmod {10} = 1, 4, 7, 6, 5, 6, 3, 6, 9, 0, 1, 6, 3, 6, 5, 6, 7, 4, 9, 0, 1, 4, 7, 6, 5,\dots$ has a period length $20$.
$a[4]a \pmod {10} = 1, 4, 7, 6, 5, 6, 3, 6, 9, 0, 1, 6, 3, 6, 5, 6, 7, 4, 9, 0, 1, 4, 7, 6, 5,\dots$ has a period length $20$.

$\cdots$

$a[k]a \pmod {10} = 1, 4, 7, 6, 5, 6, 3, 6, 9, 0, 1, 6, 3, 6, 5, 6, 7, 4, 9, 0, 1, 4, 7, 6, 5,\dots$ has a period length $20$, for any $k \in \mathbb{N}-\{0,1,2\}$.

Let $b$ be an integer greater than $a$. Then, in radix-$g$, we can say that $(g=10 \wedge n>2) \Rightarrow a[n]b \neq b[n]a$, whereas $(g=10 \wedge n<3) \Rightarrow a[n]b = b[n]a$.
Consequently, given any $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, $(g=10$ $\wedge$ (last digit period length $> g))\Rightarrow a[n]b \neq b[n]a$ holds for (almost) all $a$ and $b$.

**Question:** *For which values of $g$ the last statement above is also true?*

Comment: Almost all power towers (with identical entries) modulo some positive integer become soon stationary that is the residue does not change anymore if another entry is added in the tower.

Comment: This is why we can search for prime factors of , say , "Grahams number $+2$" although we cannot work with the full number.

Comment: @Peter Yeah, I know this very well since my trilogy of papers about the constancy of the congruence speed of tetration (e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.02622). My point is to understand if, given any nontrivial value of $g$, we can show that $a[n]b$ is commutative for any $a < b$ if and only if the period length of the final digit of $a[n]a$ is greater than $g$.